# one of the cascading Dropdownlists does not retain value on Checkbox checked event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html-select

Below is my checkbox and corresponding cascading dropdownlists. Now my requirements are:

```
<table cellpadding="2" border="0" style="margin-left: 2px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblChk" runat="server" Text="checkbox"> </asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk1_CheckedChanged" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="2" border="0" style="margin-left: 2px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 130px" class="Label">DDL1
        </td>
        <td> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" runat="server" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Label">DDL2
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL2" runat="server" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL2_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Label">DDL3
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL3" runat="server" Width="200px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

1. On unchecking the checkbox, the dropdowns would get enabled and get populated with default values from database
2. Upon checking these dropdowns should simply get disabled

The issue here is the last dropdown resets to 0th index on checking the checkbox.
Upon analysis, I got a workaround wherein I added empty server side OnSelectedIndexChanged event and it worked. But however, I do not wish to go ahead with this and would like to know the cause and resolution for this issue

Comment: can you share your `chk1_CheckedChanged`code

Comment: if (!chk.Checked)
            {
                
                    DDL1.SelectedValue = "some value";
                    
                        DataBindMidIndustry(DDL1.SelectedValue, DDL2, "DDL2's selected value", false);//Binds DDL2 and sets a selected value


                    
                        DataBindSubSector(DDL2.SelectedValue, DDL3, "DDL3's selected value", false);//Binds DDL2 and sets a selected value
                    
                
                
                
            }